# Specific Oracle SQL Query (Join, Union..?)

Tags: sql, oracle, join, outer-join

I've a question for a Query-Statement. I just don't get it right...

With the following Select

```
Select
    dt_root.parentid, dt_root.dataid, dt_root.name, dt_root.modifydate
from
    dtree dt_root
where
    dt_root.parentid in (18524213,18523767)
```

i'm getting this table:

[image: Table]

Is it possible, that when i have the same file in .dwg and .pdf that i will be in one row, like this:

```
DATAID_DWG | NAME_DWG | MDFDATE_DWG | DATAID_PDF | NAME_PDF | MDFDATE_PDF
```

I tryed a lot of different joins, but i don't get it.

Thanks for helping!

Comment: And what are you expecting the PARENTID, DATAID to be? They are different for both files. The date as well but here you could take the last one for instance.

Comment: Will help if you show us your desire ouput. Right now you only put the field name but dont show what you want there. I can guess you want a row with vizualization.pdf and vizualization.dwg, but what about test1.dwg? We ignore that or create a row with  `null`  in the pdf part?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if you want

- `INNER JOIN` mean show only rows with both filename
- Or `FULL JOIN` and in that case handle `NULL` on each side.

**INNER JOIN**

```
SELECT 
       dt_A.DataID     AS DATAID_DWG,
       dt_A.Name       AS NAME_DWG,
       dt_A.ModifyDate AS MDFDATE_DWG,
       dt_B.DataID     AS DATAID_PDF,
       dt_B.Name       AS NAME_PDF,
       dt_B.ModifyDate AS MDFDATE_PDF
FROM 
           dtree dt_A
INNER JOIN dtree dt_B
       ON substr(dt_A.name, 0, length(dt_A.name)-4) 
        = substr(dt_B.name, 0, length(dt_B.name)-4)
      AND dt_A.DATAID <> dt_B.DATAID

WHERE substr (dt_A.name, -4) = '.dwg' 
  AND substr (dt_B.name, -4) = '.pdf'
```

**FULL JOIN**: I show some partial null handling. You would need to arrange the rest of the fields.

```
SELECT 
       CASE 
           WHEN dt_A NOT NULL THEN dt_A.Name
           ELSE '' 
       END AS   DATAID_DWG,
       NAME_DWG ,
       MDFDATE_DWG,
       DATAID_PDF,
       NAME_PDF,
       MDFDATE_PDF
FROM 
          dtree dt_A
FULL JOIN dtree dt_B
       ON substr(dt_A.name, 0, length(dt_A.name)-4) 
        = substr(dt_B.name, 0, length(dt_B.name)-4)
      AND dt_A.DATAID <> dt_B.DATAID

WHERE substr (dt_A.name, -4) = '.dwg' 
  AND substr (dt_B.name, -4) = '.pdf'
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! The Inner Join works, but i would prefer the Full Join, but when i run this statement, i get the following error:
ORA-00920: invalid relational operator

       CASE 
           WHEN dt_A NOT NULL THEN dt_A.DataID
           ELSE ''
       AS DATAID_DWG,
       CASE
        WHEN dt_A NOT NULL THEN dt_A.Name
           ELSE ''
       AS NAME_DWG,

and so on... i tried also with IS NOT NULL but then i'm getting the ORA-00905: missing keyword  Error....

Comment: I miss one `END` on the `CASE` statement, I just fix it. but again you have to play with field name to match your require. And I cant help there unless you provide more info regarding your desire output.

Comment: the desired output is exactly like the full join statement. I select all DWG with PDF, all DWG without PDF, and all PDF without DWG. I have to check afterwards this 3 options. I updated my query, but the error doesn't disappear.  Does FULL JOIN exists for Oracle SQL?

Comment: hmm ok thx. i don't get it why it doesn't work. It's still the error "ORA-00920: invalid relational operator" :-/

Comment: Can you prepare a fiddle with your schema here www.sqlfiddle.com?

Comment: Try [**NOW**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f6e25a/5) I miss the `IS NOT`. You miss the `dt_A.name` on each `CASE`. Also have to change `timestamp` to `varchar` because got a weird error and didnt want to investigate. And integer `CASE` change `''` for `-1`

Comment: you mean this weird error: ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected DATE got CHAR?
I've got this in my system, i can't change from timestamp to varchar.

Comment: Well that timestamp error is for another question. Lets work with the fiddle using varchar to see if we can get the result you want.  Here is another [**Fix**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f6e25a/9).  to include the null result. You will have to decide what rows you want to show.

Comment: I replaced the '' with sysdate and that worked, more or less. It doesn't crashed but has just one result, with the dwg&pdf and not the dwg&null result.

Comment: Your fix crashed also. Inconsistent datatypes

Comment: This works http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f6e25a/9 If you change to date or timestamp you have to fix the `ELSE` part in the `CASE`

Comment: yes, in jsfiddle i get 2 results, and in my system i get just 1. i think i'm done.... http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f6e25a/11

Comment: Fiddle have 5 result. why you see only 2?

Comment: This is my final fiddle. http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f6e25a/10, this remove the  html file because isnt dwg or pdf. Check the is NULL part... is `A.name is null` with `substring(B.name)`

Comment: Now real last. http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/6e1ba/1 Here I add another pdf file in the schema. So you can see the result on both sides. See how I dont use the parentID in my where?

Comment: Yours and mine query works fine in Jsfiddle, but in my system i just get 1 result. Thats just weird. thanks for your help, you'r awesome. but i'm done.